# "There are stopped jobs" when I try to quit terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal.app

I am using terminal.app on a MacBookPro running Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5. When I try to `exit` the terminal, I get a message "There are stopped jobs" and the `exit` fails.

What does this error message mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You may want to read the following thread:

http://serverfault.com/questions/240155/how-can-i-kill-all-stopped-jobs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that this happens is because there is a stopped job still open in that terminal window (duh!). Typically this happens when a program is run and suspended (with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>).

To get a list of such jobs, use the command `jobs` on the terminal and use `fg` to revive each of those jobs and quit them properly. Once this is done, terminal can be `exit`ed normally.

Of course, a simpler solution (not one that I would advise, though) would be to simply close the terminal with the mouse, ignoring any warning messages.

[[source](http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?125669-Terminal-message-There-are-Stopped-Jobs)]